# adding a section above or beyond a selected section

Tags: javascript, html

I want to enable the user to add section at any place that he chooses. 
below a selected section or above it,
for example:

```
  <add section button>
0. here section 0
   <add section button>
```

then if user click on `<add section button>` that below the section numbered **0** it should like:

```
  <add section button>
0. here section 0
   <add section button>
1. here section 1
   <add section button>
```

If user click again on `<add section button>` that below the section numbered **0** it should like:

```
  <add section button>
0. here section 0
   <add section button>
2. here section 2
   <add section button>
1. here section 1
   <add section button>
```

If user click **again** on `<add section button>` that below the section numbered **0** it should like:

```
  <add section button>
0. here section 0
   <add section button>
3. here section 3
   <add section button>
2. here section 2
   <add section button>
1. here section 1
   <add section button>
```

but for this secenario I'm getting:

[image]

---

**Secenario 2:**

If user click the button that above section 0 once, and the click the button that above section 1 that should look like:

```
  <add section button>
2. here section 2
   <add section button>
1. here section 1
   <add section button>
0. here section 0
   <add section button>
```

but it looks like:
[image]

Here my full code:

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .collapsible {
      background-color: #777;
      color: white;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .content {
      padding: 0 18px;
      display: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #90ee90;
    }

    body {
      font-size: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function getListItem(dir) {
      if (dir == 'up')
        return `
      <li>
        <button type="button" class="collapsible">Section ` + (++countElem) + `</button>
        <div class="content">
          <button>upload file</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="btn-down">
        <button onclick="addSection('down',this)">Add Section </button>
      </li>`;
      else
        return `<li class="btn-up">
        <button onclick="addSection('up',this)">Add Section </button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="button" class="collapsible">Section ` + (++countElem) + `</button>
        <div class="content">
          <button>upload file</button>
        </div>
      </li>`;
    }


    var countElem = 0;

    function addSection(dir, el) {
      var sibling;
      //  if (dir == 'up')
      sibling = el.parentElement;
      // else
      //   sibling = el.nextElementSibling;

      while (sibling) {
        if (dir == 'down' && sibling.matches('.btn-down')) {
          // var node = document.createElement("li"); // Create a <li> node
          // var textnode = document.createTextNode("New li Item was added Up!"); // Create a text node
          // node.appendChild(textnode);
          // return sibling.parentNode.insertBefore(node, node.nextSibling);
          $(el.parentNode).prepend(getListItem('down'));
          break;
        } else if (dir == 'up' && sibling.matches('.btn-up')) {
          // var node = document.createElement(getListItem()); // Create a <li> node
          // var textnode = document.createTextNode("test"); // Create a text node
          // var textnode = document.createht
          // node.appendChild(textnode);
          // return sibling.parentNode.insertBefore(node, sibling);
          $(el.parentNode).append(getListItem('up'));
          break;
        }
        // if (dir == 'up')
        sibling = sibling.previousElementSibling
        // else
        //   sibling = sibling.nextElementSibling;
      }
      // handleEvents();
    }


   
  </script>
  <div id="header">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="btn-up">
        <button onclick="addSection('up',this)">Add Section </button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="button" class="collapsible">Section 0</button>
        <div class="content">
          <button>upload file</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="btn-down">
        <button onclick="addSection('down',this)">Add Section </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Shouldn't every section come with an add above and below button? Otherwise how can you tell if you want to add a new section above or below the clicked button?

Comment: It will be less pretty with two buttons for each section @EmielZuurbier

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem or specific question is. Your code seems to do the right thing.

Comment: This is acting exactly how it should since the first button it telling it to append before the rest of the other sections *"AppendBefore"* and the `addSection('down',this)` is appending last. You might want to rethink the structure of this as it might be easier to work with. You could no doubt write one function to deal with the appending too. Take your time and plan things out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your code seems to work fine you are asking for a way to accomplish something that seems impossible to achieve with a single button per section. Adding a second button to each section, so that a section has a up and down button, would solve the problem easily.

I took the effort to create a "simplified" version with some additional CSS to show that it does not have to be *less pretty* when adding a second button. You can come a long way with styling to make the buttons more appealing to you and the user.

Check out the example below.

```js
let sectionIndex = 0;

function addSection(position, relation) {
  const template = `
    <li class="section">
      <button aria-label="Add section above" class="section__button section__button--up" value="beforebegin">&#8593;</button>
      <button aria-label="Add section below" class="section__button section__button--down" value="afterend">&#8595;</button>
      <span class="section__label">Section ${++sectionIndex}</span>
    </li>`;
  relation.insertAdjacentHTML(position, template);
}

const sections = document.querySelector('.js-sections');
sections.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const button = event.target.closest('.section__button');
  if (button !== null) {
    const position = button.value;
    const relation = button.parentElement;
    addSection(position, relation);
  }
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 3em 3em;
  grid-template-columns: 3em 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "up label"
    "down label";
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section__button {
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out, background-color 250ms ease-in-out;;
}

.section__button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.section:hover .section__button {
  opacity: 1;
}

.section__button--up {
  grid-area: up;
}

.section:hover .section__button--up {
  background-color: #215467;
}

.section__button--down {
  grid-area: down;
}

.section:hover .section__button--down {
  background-color: #e2a418;
}

.section:hover .section__button:hover {
  background-color: #55c773;
}

.section__label {
  grid-area: label;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 2em 5em 2em 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<ul class="js-sections">

  <li class="section">
    <button aria-label="Add section above" class="section__button section__button--up" value="beforebegin">&#8593;</button>
    <button aria-label="Add section below" class="section__button section__button--down" value="afterend">&#8595;</button>
    <span class="section__label">Section 0</span>
  </li>
  
</ul>
```